# Why do we get HTTP 503 service unavailable?

Tags: java, python, http, https, http-status-codes

I know that http 503 means that the "server is unavailable" as mentioned in [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503). But, if the server is unavailable or offline, then how is *that server* able to return a 503 response ? Is the client getting timed out and assuming a 503?

**UPDATE** -
I learned that there is often "middle man" such as a load balancer which gives the 503 when the backend is down. So, what if there is no middle man? Would you get an http 408 in that case?

PS - Java and Python tags are added only to get more attention from developers who are likely to know the answer to this question.

Comment: 503 is generally returns by load balancers, proxies, or CDNs when they themselves are up but their origin/backend is down.

Comment: @jordanm - thanks. So, if there was no middle man like a load balancer, then would we get http 408 when the server is down ?

Answer (score 2):

`50x` errors are for application errors. This means that if you have for example Apache2 or Nginx web server and that server communicate with backend application which is currently unavailable (down, starting, freezed, etc) you get this 503 error.

> YOU -----> Apache2/Nginx web server ------> app backend = you will get 200
> response.

> YOU -----> Apache2/Nginx web server --XXX--> app backend = you will get 503
> error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added edited my question and added an update.